# Sharing Knowledge: pushing a [key, value] to an array with the "push" Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The idea is to create a function, that takes an object as parameter and returns each property with its type.

```js
const robot = {
  version: 16,
  name: 'Cleaner 3000',
  coords: [345, 12],
};

robotSchema(robot) // [['version', 'number'], ['name', 'string'], ['coords', 'object']]
```

Comment: @adiga, I'm not asking a question, but sharing knowledge that can be helpfull to javscript beginner

Answer (score 1):

just surround the items you would like to push with the square brackets `[]`

```js
function robotSchema(robot) {
  let arr = [];
 
  for(let key in robot){
    arr.push([key, typeof robot[key]]); // 
  }

  return arr;
}

const robot = { version: 16, name: 'Cleaner 3000', coords: [345, 12], }; 

console.log( robotSchema(robot) )
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys to loop over your object

```js
const robot = { version: 16, name: 'Cleaner 3000', coords: [345, 12], }; 

const foo = (arr) => {
  return Object.keys(robot).map(rec => {
    return [rec, typeof robot[rec]]
  })
}

console.log(foo(robot))
```